# Kaa authentication over MongoDB

Tags: kaa

I can't receive data on my mongodb2.6 when authentification=true, by the way, am writen in authentification credentials user and password of my kaa database.
But and i can send data when authentification is disabled.
I dont know if it is a problem of mongodb version or a user Roles

Any hint please

Answer (score 0):

Check [authentication mechanisms](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/core/authentication/#authentication-mechanisms) in your MongoDB.
Kaa supports MongoDB’s default authentication challenge and response mechanism (MONGODB-CR).